# Yamaha psr-e413 does not appear as midi device (ubuntu 20.10)

Tags: 20.10, midi

Hello‚ I've recently updated from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.10 and am now having extreme difficulties setting up my keyboard as a midi device as before. It does not appear under lsusb nor under aconnect. This is the kernel log:
[/var/log/kernel.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4AOV.png)

port 3 might be genuinely broken but all other ports report a "connect-debounce" failed error.
I am **dumb** so please explain in simple terms if possible‚ thank you!

Comment: Do any other USB devices work at the same port(s)?

Comment: try doing the following command: lsusb > lsusb.txt

Comment: the command will output the information into a text file instead of the screen and you can share/link to the file instead so we can all have a clear and complete readout. ( doing > filename.txt works on just about anything that outputs text in terminal)